# phpMyAdmin, pdo, mysqli, wampserver: re: login-nav

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, mysqli, pdo

Okay, so I was following a tutorial on bootstrap logins etc.
(frustratingly a large number of these tutorials online are incomplete or encounter various issues example class mysqli)

Anyway, I kept getting the class mysqli issue, and as I spend days fixing it for no point, i decided to work together a mix of mysqli and pdo to login/query/connect etc as a workaround.

However I ended up with a strange outcome.

When I use chrome I run > index.php > then I dropdown login > login.php
When I use IE I run > index.php > then i dropdown login > home_.php >

exactly the same code.

It was more of a test site, so once I started getting issues I redirected the index file to home_.php via config_.php rather than recode everything to pdo.

I even made a video of it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wjHfbatcbAs

2nd strange thing.

So I made two directories and deleted the additional files: home_.php config_.php and class.user_.php from one of them.

folder 1
the chrome version WORKS without the additonal files
the I.E version BREAKS

folder 2
chrome does as video
i.e does as video

Comment: I'm not able to be of too much assistance as I'm currently on mobile, but PHP doesn't differ from what kind of browser you use. And without seeing specific error messages and your code, it's hard to tell.

Comment: Thanks. Spoke to my cousin, he said that it was the session being active.